# Isotope: positioning of elements that have different heights

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, jquery-isotope

I'm using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) plugin to form a grid of elements on my page. Those elements have different heights and are sorted by `data-time` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item" data-time="3" style="height:50px;">1</div>
    <div class="item" data-time="2" style="height:65px;">2</div>
    <div class="item" data-time="1" style="height:30px;">3</div>
    <div class="item" data-time="0" style="height:80px;">4</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function($){
    $('#container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        getSortData: {
            time: '[data-time]',
        },
        sortBy: 'time',
        sortAscending: false
    });
}(jQuery));
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/62LjjLfy/) jsfiddle example of what I have so far.

So, as you can see the 4th element is appended to the least filled "column".

```
1 2 3
    4
```

I would like isotope to place it under the 1st element.

```
1 2 3
4
```

I know that it could be achieved by enabling `fitRows` layout ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z63hs6su/1/)), but this layout mode is suited for equal height elements.

Is there any "painless" way to make isotope ignore the shortest "column" and append elements on "N elements per row" basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems to be impossible. Try not to use isotope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a div into a .item element and counting .list-item-wrapper height every time you use isotop plugin

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="list"><li class="item"><div class="list-item-wrapper">...< /div></li></ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var maxHeight = 0,
    currentElementHeight;
$.each($('ul.list').find('li').find('.list-item-wrapper'), function(key, value) {
    currentElementHeight = parseInt($(value).height());
    if ( currentElementHeight > maxHeight ) {
        maxHeight = currentElementHeight;
    }
});
productCatalog.find('li').css('height', maxHeight);
```

This will help.